# thinktecture identityserver v3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

Trying to use Thinctecture identityserver v3 as a simple sts for multiple mvc applications.
I'm able to walk through the sample applications provided and the run fine but they all use embedded identityserver.  I need the identityserver to be a separate application so that I can use it as the sts for several apps.  When I try to run the identityserver and connect the sample mvc application to it seem to be missing  something.

The sample mvc app  uses katana

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions...
```

but I'm just not understanding how to correctly config for external app service. 
My guess is I'm not using the right endpoint.

Here is my relying party configuration as mvc. 
I then have the latest IS v3 running untouched here:
     :44333

In the mvc app whenever I try to navigate to a view that requires authorization I get the exception.

Stack Trace:

```
[HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).]
   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() +87960
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetDocumentAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +496

[IOException: Unable to get document from: https://localhost:44333/.well-known/openid-configuration]
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetDocumentAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +830
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +512
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetConfigurationAsync>d__3.MoveNext() +1332
```

here is the full auth config in the mvc app.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    //Authority = "https://localhost:44319/identity",
    Authority = "https://localhost:44333",
    ClientId = "mvc",
    Scope = "openid profile roles",
    RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44319/",

    SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
    UseTokenLifetime = false,

    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
            {
                var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                // we want to keep first name, last name, subject and roles
                var givenName = id.FindFirst(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName);
                var familyName = id.FindFirst(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName);
                var sub = id.FindFirst(Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject);
                var roles = id.FindAll(Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                // create new identity and set name and role claim type
                var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
                    id.AuthenticationType,
                    Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName,
                    Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                nid.AddClaim(givenName);
                nid.AddClaim(familyName);
                nid.AddClaim(sub);
                nid.AddClaims(roles);

                // keep the id_token for logout
                nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                // add some other app specific claim
                nid.AddClaim(new Claim("app_specific", "some data"));

                n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                    nid,
                    n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
            },
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
            {
                if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                {
                    var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                    if (idTokenHint != null)
                    {
                        n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well I got a little further, but still would appreciate guidance to my stupidity if anyone is willing to offer.   By changing authority and adding the MeadataAddress to mvc configuration I was about to get it to work. Authority = "https://idsrv3.com",
                MetadataAddress = "https://localhost:44333/core/.well-known/openid-configuration",

Comment: could you add the content of the Startup.cs file you used to configure IdentityServerv3 ? I also created a tutorial to configure IdSrv3, there you have the configuration of Idsrv and also an Mvc app that requesting some public resource after the user gave consent : [link to tutorial](http://cedric-dumont.com/tutorials/identityserver-v3-membershipreboot-angularjs-webapi-2-and-mvc-mix-it-introduction/)

Comment: I encourage with this issue, refreshing the page solved it. It seems the STS site don't response some time.

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint is missing the `/identity` at the end